# Has edge, increase edge weight and complexity

Tags: python, igraph

I want to perform some edges operations: has edge and increase edge weight.

I tried this:

```
from igraph import *
g = Nexus.get("karate")
if g.es.select(_from=0, _target=1):
    g.es.select(_from=0, _target=1)['weight'] += 1
else:
    g.add_edge(0, 1, weight=1)
```

I have problems: The operator to increase:

```
 g.es.select(_from=0, _target=1)['weight'] += 1 # not work
```

Not work, however, when process add new edge weight this works. E.g.:

```
 g.es.select(_from=0, _target=1)['weight'] = 200000 # this is ok
```

Addition, I would like something more efficient or elegant. For instance, there is operation/function computationally more efficient to perform this operation in the library IGRAPH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, there are a few things that you should know to understand why the increase operation does not work.

First of all, `g.es.select()` returns an `EdgeSeq` object, i.e. an edge sequence. In your case, if the edge exists, it returns an edge sequence of length 1, otherwise it returns an edge sequence of length zero:

```
>>> edges = g.es.select(_from=0, _to=1)
>>> edges
<igraph.EdgeSeq at 0x10ce62350>
>>> len(edges)
1
```

Second, using the `['weight']` operation on an `EdgeSeq` will return a *list* that contains the weight attribute of each edge in the `EdgeSeq`:

```
>>> edges["weight"]
[42]
```

Third, `x += 1` is essentially equivalent to `x = x + 1`, so when you try to increase the weight using `+=`, you try to *append* 1 to the list instead (since `x` is a list, see my second point), which won't work since you can only append another list to a list. Furthermore, the list you get is only a *copy* of the edge attributes anyway, so modifying it does not alter the edge attributes:

```
>>> edges["weight"] += 1
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>> edges["weight"] += [1]
>>> edges["weight"]
[42]
```

The simplest solution is to get a single `Edge` object from the `EdgeSeq` and modify that, because using the `['weight']` operation on an `Edge` will return the weight as a single element, which you can increase and write back to the edge using the `+=` operator in a concise way:

```
>>> edge = edges[0]
>>> edge
igraph.Edge(<igraph.Graph object at 0x10d788148>, 0, {'weight': 42})
>>> edge["weight"] += 1
>>> edge
igraph.Edge(<igraph.Graph object at 0x10d788148>, 0, {'weight': 43})
```

However, I would avoid `g.es.select` in this case because it evaluates every single edge in `g.es` in order to find the ones that satisfy your criteria. Instead of that, I would use `g.get_eid()` to get the ID of the edge I'm looking for and then use `g.es[edge_id]` to find the appropriate edge:

```
eid = g.get_eid(0, 1, error=False)
if eid >= 0:
    g.es[eid]["weight"] += 1
else:
    g.add_edge(0, 1, weight=1)
```

An alternative way is to recognize that igraph objects can be treated as adjacency matrices. When the graph has an edge attribute named `weight`, calling `g[source, target]` returns the weight of the edge between the given source and target vertices and this can also be used to set the weight of course. When the graph does not have an edge attribute named `weight`, `g[source, target]` is simply 1 if `source` and `target` are connected and zero otherwise. So, you can also do this:

```
g = Nexus.get('karate')
g.es["weight"] = 1       # to ensure that existing edges have weight=1
g[0,1] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For just **working**,(neither efficient nor elegant)

```
>>> from igraph import *
>>> g = Nexus.get('karate')
>>> print g.es.select(_from=0, _target=1)['weight'] # to see the value
[4.0]
>>> if g.es.select(_from=0, _target=1):
...     buff = g.es.select(_from=0, _target=1)['weight']
...     buff[0] += 1   
...     g.es.select(_from=0, _target=1)['weight'] = buff
... else:
...     g.add_edge(0, 1, weight=1)
>>> print g.es.select(_from=0, _target=1)['weight'] # to see the value
[5.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend networkx for this.  Here is the same code.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.karate_club_graph()

#you can assign all with a starting weight
for x,y in G.edges_iter():
    G.add_edge(x,y,weight=1)

# then add more as you come across them.
for x,y in SomeIterableAffectingTheGraph:
    G.edge[x][y]['weight']+=1
```